# Unable to call woocommerce hook in my custom php file

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, hooks

**It is not a plugin, it is just a simple file call on ajax.**

My Js code

```
$('.pkg-btn').click(function(){
    var this_id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var url = templateUrl+'/tw-add-to-cart-ajax.php';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: ({selected_package_id: this_id}),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data1) {
            console.log(data1);
            $('#conditions').show();
        }
    });
});
```

My php file code

```
<?php

//        $product_id = $_POST['selected_package_id'];
//        echo $product_id; // It displays id - works fine here
//        exit();

    add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'custome_add_to_cart');

    function custome_add_to_cart() {

         echo 'hook called'; // This is not showing any message
         exit();

        global $woocommerce;
        $product_id = $_POST['selected_package_id'];

        echo $product_id; // This is not displaying id
        exit();

        $found = false;
        //check if product already in cart
        if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
                $_product = $values['data'];
                if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
                    $found = true;
            }
            // if product not found, add it
            if ( ! $found ){
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
            }
        } else {
            // if no products in cart, add it
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
        }
    }
```

In php file before calling hook I get the passed id anf echo it. It is showing the id, means js passing data to php and php also getting that id but when I call hook it shows error: 
**jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 POST domain-url/wp-content/themes/my-theme-folder/tw-add-to-cart-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)** 
and message displaying in network **This request has no response data available**

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it all wrong, place your code like the following in your file.

```
<?php

echo 'hook called'; // This is not showing any message
    exit();

global $woocommerce;
$product_id = $_POST['selected_package_id'];

echo $product_id; // This is not displaying id
exit();

$found = false;
//check if product already in cart
if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) > 0 ) {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        if ( $_product->id == $product_id )
            $found = true;
    }
    // if product not found, add it
    if ( ! $found ){
        WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
    }
} else {
    // if no products in cart, add it
    WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
}
```

The approach you are using to do it by hooks is not correct.